# Find All function $f(x)\in \Bbb{R}[x]$ satisfying $f(x)f(x+1)=f(x^2+x)$

Tags: functional-equations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: Given the functional equation of the polynomial function $f$:
$$f(x)f(x+1)=f(x^2+x),\:x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Find All function $f$ that solve the equation.

I tried to find it using the number of roots of the equation
$$f(x)=0$$
but I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: It is definitely true that $f(0)=0$ or $f(1)=1$ or $f(-1)=1.$

Comment: Context may be helpful.  Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Is $f\in\Bbb R[X]$?

Comment: The simplest example is the identity map.

Comment: Worth reading [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399182/find-all-real-polynomial-solutions-of-a-functional-equation?noredirect=1),[(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178874/an-interesting-question-of-a-polynomial-in-mathbbrx?noredirect=1)

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = x^t$ $(t \in \mathbb{R})$ are the solutions. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43964/if-fxy-fxfy-then-show-that-fx-xt-for-some-t).

Comment: @fractalletter, in the thread, it says **for all** $x,y...$ that's a stronger condition.

Comment: I think it's possible to write $f(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, examine both sides of the functional equation starting from the highest powers of $x$ on down, and iteratively conclude that $a_n=1$ and all other $a_j=0$. (unless $f$ is identically $0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $f= 0$ is a solution, as pointed out by Travis. Now, assume $f\neq 0$.

Let $d:=\deg(f)$, let $a_d$ be the leading coefficient. Divide both sides of the functional equation by $x^{2d}$ and let $x\to \infty$. It follows that $a_d^2=a_d$ and $a_d\neq 0$, so $a_d=1$. In other words, $f$ is monic. Now, let $f(x)=:x^d+g(x)$, then the functional equation becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
(g(x)+x^d)(g(x+1)+(x+1)^d)&=g(x^2+x)+(x^2+x)^d\\
g(x)g(x+1) + x^dg(x+1)+(x+1)^dg(x)=g(x^2+x).
\end{align*}
$$
If $g\neq 0$, the degree on the left is $d+\deg(g)$. This is strictly larger than $2\deg g$, which is the degree on the right. We conclude that $g=0$ and $f=x^d$. Indeed, this polynomial satisfies the functional equation.

Comment: Good point, @TravisWillse

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!